# Symfony 4.* Setting field values in controller and prevent validatinon error: This value should not be null

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms, symfony4

I am using `Symfony 4.2.3.` I have an entity called `Article` which has amongst others the following fields:

- version
- versionUserId
- versionTimestamp

which have `* @Assert\NotNull` validation mark.

I want to set value of those fields manually in the controller e.g. using:

```
$article->setVersionUserId($user);
                $article->setVersionTimestamp(new \DateTime());
                $article->setVersion(1);
```

However, as I understand `$form->isValid()`, validates an object rather than a form. Thus, to prevent `This value should not be null.` validation error **I have to set value of those fields before validating the form. How to achieve this?**

---

My controller:

```
  public function article_edit($action, Request $request)
        {
    $form = $this->createForm(ArticleType::class);  

        // Customize the form
        $form->remove("versionTimestamp");
        $form->remove("versionUserId");
        $form->remove("version");
        $form->add('save', SubmitType::class, ['label' => 'Zapisz']);

        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $article = $form->getData();
            /*
                $article->setVersionUserId($user);
                $article->setVersionTimestamp(new \DateTime());
                $article->setVersion(1);
            */
/.../
```

Comment: check this out https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/form.html#validation-groups

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as Omar Makled commented, [validation groups](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/form.html#validation-groups) are one way to achieve this. TBH, I would prefer a different approach:

```
$article = new Article();
$article->setVersionUserId($user);
$article->setVersionTimestamp(new \DateTime());
$article->setVersion(1);

$form = $this->createForm(ArticleType::class, $article); // <- preset
$form->add('save', SubmitType::class, ['label' => 'Zapisz']);

if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
    $article = $form->getData();
    // do other stuff...
}
```

*(note: calling a field "userId" is weird, when you assign a User to it, but that's just me)*

Answer (score 0):

I think a preSubmit event is the best way to acheive what you want https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/events.html